# Use select dropdown whitout PHP in EXPRESSION ENGINE

Tags: expressionengine

This is my situation :

```
<form action=“destinationpage/”>
     <select name=“localita” id=“localita” >
     <option></option>
     {exp:channel:entries channel="localita"}
     <option>{nome_localita}</option>
     {/exp:channel:entries}
     </select>
</form>
```

How can i get the select value not using php on my action form page? 
I need to have : `mywebsite.com/destinationpage/SELECTVALUE`

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Use a segment variable.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920931/how-to-pass-a-parameter-value-from-a-hyperlink-on-one-page-to-another-page-in-ex

Comment: Reading this over again... I think I misunderstood.  I think you just need a little javascript.  Here's one way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938341/creating-drop-menu-navigation-with-select